# Knapsack Problem: Why do I need a 2 dimensional DP Matrix

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I came across some classical Knapsack solutions and they always build a 2-dimensional DP array.
In my opinion, my code below solves the classical knapsack problem but with only a 1-dim DP array.
Can someone tell me where my solution does not work or why it is computationally inefficient compared to the 2D-DP version?

A 2D-DP version can be found here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/

example input:

```
weights = [(3,30),(2,20),(1,50),(4,30)]
constraint = 5
```

And my solution:

```
def knapsack(weights,constraint):
    n = len(weights)

    #define dp array
    dp = [0]*(constraint+1) 

    #start filling in the array
    for k in weights:
        for i in range(constraint,k[0]-1,-1):
            dp[i] = max(dp[i],dp[i-k[0]]+k[1])
    return dp[constraint]
```

Comment: Well, your `weights` input is a 2D array.  Do you have a link to a contrasting solution you don't like?

Comment: Do you have a test case where your code doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Tim - thanks for your answer, makes sense but would it be computationally inefficient to transform input data in such a 2d array? 

[link] (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/)

Comment: @TimRoberts OP is talking about the array `dp`. Usually it is implemented with a 2D array where each row is populated from the previous row and the answer is found at the end of the final row. OP is overwriting the same row to save memory.

Comment: @SufianLatif thanks for clarifying I added some more text to my original Question. I was just wondering why most of the proposed solutions use the 2D-DP if using a 1D-DP works just as well and saves memory.

Comment: I can think of one 'problem' with your approach: while it gives you the maximum possible value you can achieve within the constraint, it won't help you to find the items. To find the items that gives you the maximum value you'll need to backtrack your way through the 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

The version using O(nW) memory is more intuitive and makes it possible to easily retrieve the subset of items that produce the optimal answer value.

But, using O(n + W) of memory, we cannot retrieve this subset directly. While it is possible to do this, using the divide-and-conquer technique as explained in https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/47247?#comment-316200.

[Sample code](https://pastebin.com/Ku30AxaC)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 
using namespace std;
using vi = vector<int>;
#define FOR(i, b) for(int i = 0; i < (b); i++)
 
template<class T>
struct Knapsack{
  int n, W;
  vector<T> dp, vl;
  vi ans, opt, wg;
 
  Knapsack(int n_, int W): n(0), W(W),
    dp(W + 1), vl(n_), opt(W + 1), wg(n_){}
  
  void Add(T v, int w){
    vl[n] = v;
    wg[n++] = w;
  }
 
  T conquer(int l, int r, int W){
    if(l == r){
      if(W >= wg[l])
        return ans.push_back(l), vl[l];
      return 0;
    }
 
    FOR(i, W + 1)
      opt[i] = dp[i] = 0;
    int m = (l + r) >> 1;
    
    for(int i = l; i <= r; i++)
      for(int sz = W; sz >= wg[i]; sz--){
        T dpCur = dp[sz - wg[i]] + vl[i];
        if(dpCur > dp[sz]){
          dp[sz] = dpCur;
          opt[sz] = i <= m ? sz : opt[sz - wg[i]];
        }
      }
    
    T ret = dp[W];
    int K = opt[W];
    T ret2 = conquer(l, m, K) + conquer(m + 1, r, W - K);
    assert(ret2 == ret);
    return ret;
  }
 
  T Solve(){
    return conquer(0, n - 1, W);
  }
};
 
 
int main(){
  cin.tie(0)->sync_with_stdio(0);
 
  int n, W, vl, wg;
  cin >> n >> W;
  Knapsack<int> ks(n, W);
 
  FOR(i, n){
    cin >> vl >> wg;
    ks.Add(vl, wg);
  }
  
  cout << ks.Solve() << endl;
}
```